# How to display first date then month?

Tags: javascript

I am using Jquery to display a calender. I have created a text-box, after clicking in the text-box the calender is opening. But when I am putting a date manually, it always taking first month, then date. But I want to make it first date then month. Suppose I am putting 19th June 2015 in this way 19/06/2015, but it is not showing as my code is counting 19 as a month. Please help.
Below is my code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $("#datepicker").datepicker();
        });
    </script>
<body>
<input type="text" id="datepicker">
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define [`dateFormat`](https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-dateFormat) property:

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy' })
```

Comment: @Amit no problem. Don't forget to accept answers if they were helpful and welcome to SO.

Answer (score 0):

Very simple, no library required:

```
var date = new Date();
var firstDay = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), 1);
var lastDay = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth() + 1, 0);
```

or you might prefer:

```
var date = new Date(), y = date.getFullYear(), m = date.getMonth();
var firstDay = new Date(y, m, 1);
var lastDay = new Date(y, m + 1, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [dateFormat](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-dateFormat)

```
$(function () {
    $("#datepicker").datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yyyy'
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change as your need,

```
var newdate = new Date();

var curr_date = newdate.getDate();

var curr_month = newdate.getMonth();

var curr_year = newdate.getFullYear();

curr_year = curr_year.toString().substr(2,2);

document.write(curr_date+"-"+curr_month+"-"+curr_year);
```